# Contact Form for React and Nodemailer not working when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have built a website with a Contact Form with React.js as my front end and Node.js & Express as my backend.

The contact form works when I serve the website locally however when I host the website the contact form does not work.

Can anyone have a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is my folder structure
 [image]

this my index.js file

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `${__dirname}/.env` });
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)

  const htmlEmail = `        
        <h3>Contact Details</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
            <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message </h3>
        <p>${req.body.message}</p>
        `;

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    }

  });
  let mailOptions = {
    from: `"NodeMailer" <mwhyuen@gmail.com>`, // sender address
    to: "mwhyuen@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    replyTo: 'testuser@mitchellsroom.com',
    subject: "New Message ✔", // Subject line
    text: `Hello New message`, // plain text body
    html: htmlEmail // html body
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(`Message sent %s, `, info)
      console.log('Message URL: %s,', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))
    }
  })



})
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('4loop/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '4loop', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

and this is my package.json scripts for the backend

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix 4loop",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix 4loop && npm run build --prefix 4loop"
  },
```

and this is the response I get when I submit me email:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 503
```

Everything works perfectly locally, however the emails do not send when I host it in Heroku

Comment: Have you added env variables in HEROKU?

Comment: Yes I did add them to Heroku

Comment: u can't use ur explicit password, u should create one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS Nodemailer POST internal server error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845114/node-js-nodemailer-post-internal-server-error-500)